# How to redirect hyperlinks with a custom chrome extension

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, google-chrome-extension

I am kind of a noob at chrome extensions. So far I have a chrome extension, which adds a context menu option that allows you to open a YouTube shorts video as a regular video.

Right clicking the short every time is quite cumbersome and I would like to find a way to redirect this to the regular video, i.e. replace "shorts/" with "watch?v=" when this hyperlink is clicked.

> I have already tried to use the chrome.webRequest module, but I really have no idea what I am doing. I also looked up some similar questions here, but I have no clue how to implement those myself. A question like this: [How to modify all links on a page with chrome extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033856/how-to-modify-all-links-on-page-with-chrome-extension?rq=3).

Comment: You'll need a content script in 'MAIN' `world` and a global click listener that checks if the event's target is a shorts link and then changes a few fields in its `data` property (commandMetadata, watchEndpoint).

Comment: Thanks, how exactly would that look? So I'm assuming a javascript file, but what would the code look like? @wOxxOm